# Remove Flash Sound Player sound instance limitation

Tags: flash, audio

However I put this together years ago I think I was probably thinking of how to play multiple sounds at the same time. Unfortunately it only plays eight sounds and then stops. How do I make this Flash script play sounds without any instance limitations?

```
import flash.external.*;
ExternalInterface.addCallback('splayerSound', null, playsound);
ExternalInterface.addCallback('splayerStop', null, stopsound);

function playsound(param)
{
 var p = param.split('&');
 if (p[1]=='0')      {sound0 = new Sound(sound0); sound0.loadSound(p[0],true);}
 else if (p[1]=='1') {sound1 = new Sound(sound1); sound1.loadSound(p[0],true);}
 else if (p[1]=='2') {sound2 = new Sound(sound2); sound2.loadSound(p[0],true);}
 else if (p[1]=='3') {sound3 = new Sound(sound3); sound3.loadSound(p[0],true);}
 else if (p[1]=='4') {sound4 = new Sound(sound4); sound4.loadSound(p[0],true);}
 else if (p[1]=='5') {sound5 = new Sound(sound5); sound5.loadSound(p[0],true);}
 else if (p[1]=='6') {sound6 = new Sound(sound6); sound6.loadSound(p[0],true);}
 else if (p[1]=='7') {sound7 = new Sound(sound7); sound7.loadSound(p[0],true);}
}

function stopsound()
{
 sound0.stop();
 delete sound0;
 var sound0:Sound = new Sound();

 sound1.stop();
 delete sound1;
 var sound1:Sound = new Sound();

 sound2.stop();
 delete sound2;
 var sound2:Sound = new Sound();

 sound3.stop();
 delete sound3;
 var sound3:Sound = new Sound();

 sound4.stop();
 delete sound4;
 var sound4:Sound = new Sound();

 sound5.stop();
 delete sound5;
 var sound5:Sound = new Sound();

 sound6.stop();
 delete sound6;
 var sound6:Sound = new Sound();

 sound7.stop();
 delete sound7;
 var sound7:Sound = new Sound();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"play multiple sounds at the same time"* ?

Comment: @Cherniv I can't understand how that can't be correctly interpreted: imagine a dog barking and a cat mowing at the same time.